# How to use multiple input using pipe in a batch file?

Tags: windows, batch-file, pipe

I'd like to use `2` inputs, (`ID` and `PASSWORD`), in a command.

The command I want to use asks me for an `ID` and a `PASSWORD` but when I use the command:

```
(echo ID && echo PASSWORD) | command
```

The `ID` is executed but not the `PASSWORD` (it waits for a password to be entered) and I don't know why...

I spent lot of time trying to find an answer but I failed...                                                                                           Is there anybody who can help me?

Comment: It strongly depends on the command you are using. Perhaps it doesn't accept input from stdin or you have to add an output delay between `echo ID` and `echo PASSWORD`, or it fails, because the way you try it always appends a space after `ID` and `PASSWORD` and your command  doesn't accept ID/Passwords with spaces ...

Comment: Actually, I'm trying to install some python modules with pip but there are securities to access a host which asks the user id and the password. But there are too many modules so I want to automate those steps.

Answer (score 3):

What you are attempting to do will rarely work, as many commands only accept a password as active input from stdin.

For instance the `telnet` command can not be scripted by design.

The `FTP` command requires specifying an external script file as an argument.

A few things to check:

Does the command offer you a way to enter the un/pw as arguments?

Look into the command's documentation, and try `command /?` to see what it accepts.

Also, some commands that do accept piped input will do so best when the input is stored in a text file and sent to it via redirection

ie `<"C:\FilePath\FileName.txt" Command`

YMMV, good luck